# How do I undo all my previous github actions?

Tags: git, github

I have been trying to upload my React/Next.js project on github using git commands on the terminal, but ran into erros multiple times across multiple days, and at this point everytime I try pushing it I am bombarded with my previous commits that I do not understand.

I tried following youtube tutorials but they all failed to help at some point, I think I have made too many attempts using the git commands, and I want to know how to start this entire thing from scratch and remove all the existing mess I have made

Answer (score 1):

Brute force wipe-everything-at-origin-command generator:

```
printf 'git push origin'; git ls-remote --refs | awk '{printf " +:%s",$2}'
```

Run the command that generates and you'll wipe the origin repo's entire history. Note that this will *break* the push defaults in simple and matching modes (simple is the factory default setting), you'll have to do explicit pushes to get your initial branches pushed.

Answer (score 1):

1. Delete the repository on GitHub (under the repository's 'Settings' tab, scroll down to the "Danger Zone" and click the "Delete this repository" button).
2. Create a new repository on GitHub for your project. It can use the same name as the previous repository.
3. On your local filesystem in the project's directory, find and delete the '.git' directory. This is usually hidden by the operating system by default, so you may have to take some extra steps to see the directory. On the terminal, the command would be `rm -Rf .git`.
4. Follow the steps GitHub gives you to re-initialize you local repository with git commands. It should include running `git init` inside your project's directory in order to re-create the `.git` directory, and `git remote add origin [...]` to setup GitHub as a remote, then `git push origin main` to push your local files to your new remote repository.